# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los paquetes controller, services, repository y model en sprint boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Y en que clase se realizan las validaciones de formulario?

Comment: Hola @KEVIN JEAN PIER VELIZ BRUNO, te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como preguntar, de esa manera evitarás votos negativos, cierre de pregunta y accederás a respuestas de mejor calidad. Las preguntas deben estar enfocadas en un solo tema y si es necesario, adjuntar el código usado.

Comment: Bienvenido Kevin, agrega lo que investigaste por favor, tus preguntas deben realizarse con base en [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 3):

1. La clase `controller` es la que se encarga de recibir la petición (del cliente). Es aquí donde indicas, por ejemplo, si son métodos GET, POST, PUT...
   Tambien defines los objetos de entrada y salida (los DTOs que vas a utilizar), si se necesitan queryParams, uriParams...
2. La clase `service` es la que se encarga de realizar la lógica de negocio, esto es, aquí por ejemplo realizarás llamadas a repositorios, y trabajarás sobre esos datos de las entidades, mapeos, lógica (swicht, ifs o cualquier tipo de lógica necesaria)...
3. La clase `repository`, es la que se encarga del acceso a base de datos. En ella puedes definir la entidad que vas a utilizar, el tipo de dato que usa la PK, y los métodos (o queries) que utilizarás para acceder a la base de datos.
4. La clase `model` es la que se encarga de definir tu entidad, es decir, tendrá los atributos necesarios de la entidad (que pueden tener sus propios nombres o los mismos de base de datos), la clave primaria, las relaciones (oneToMany, manyToOne...)

Te pongo un ejemplo muy básico de cada una de ellas.

Clase controller

```
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Page<MyEntity>> getAll(    
        return new ResponseEntity<MyEntity>(myService, null, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Clase Service

```
@Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<MyEntity> getAll() { 
       //logica del servicio si aplica
       return myRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Clase Repository

```
    public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
//El hecho de extender JPARepository me crea automáticamente métodos como findAll, //findById, save...
    }
```

Clase Model

```
@Entity(name = "nombreEntidad")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

Te añado esta documentación como ayuda:

[controller-service-repository](https://tom-collings.medium.com/controller-service-repository-16e29a4684e5)

[Arquitectura de controlador-servicio-repositorio](https://laravel.io/forum/06-17-2014-controller-service-repository-architecture)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayúdanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio respondiendo a preguntas basadas en [ask], saludos.